# Store JSON on CORS enabled backend

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, cordova

Okay so I have come here to ask this after quite a few attempts.

**My Aim:**

1. I am building a Phonegap app for android which uses quite a large number of JSON files. The contents of the JSON files also changes quite frequently. Currently, I am providing the JSON files in the app itself. But since the changes are frequent, I update it on PlayStore and my users have to update it after every few days.
2. To solve this issue, I want to host the JSON online so that my app can update the JSON without app update ( I can use localStorage, etc. but that's not the real issue).
3. I want to use Parse.com 's backend to store the JSON files (because of the ease they provide to update the data). I wrote a code:

```js
$.getJSON('myurl.parseapp.com/file.json', function(json) {
    // do something here
});
```

I got the error `Cross Origin Request Blocked`. So I read about it and online they say that you have to enable CORS on your server before you can make such access.

I don't know any way of enabling it on Parse.

I also tried using JSONP plugin [See here which one](https://github.com/jaubourg/jquery-jsonp) but it always went to the `error` state instead of `success`. I read it online and they say my site is not returning a correct JSON(What?). What is a correct JSON? It may here be noted that I have not configured my backend to handle the callback as Parse does not provide this( I guess ).

Then also, I went to online tools [like this](http://myjson.com) which allow hosting JSON with CORS enabled backend. But the main problem is that **they** provide me URL to the JSON and I kind of don't like it because logic of my code requires to use some custom names and numbers. Also, updating it is a little difficult.

I have not worked with any other backend before.

Can anyone help me out.

**TL;DR**

I am looking for a backend that:
1. Can host my JSON files and enable CORS.
2. Allows easy updating of the JSON files. 
3. Be free. :)

Thanks.

Comment: The poster may have asked for a recommendation for a service but it turned out all they needed was help with the API for the service they were already using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good people at parse.com say they have enabled CORS on their service. The article is here 
http://blog.parse.com/2012/01/19/javascript-and-user-authentication-for-the-rest-api/

"First, we’re launching support for cross-origin resource sharing, so that you can use Parse from Javascript that runs on any site. With the X-Parse-Application-Id and X-Parse-REST-API-Key headers, so that you can access Parse from Javascript on any domain."

Their api requires that you include some headers in your request like this:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Message", true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Parse-Application-Id", "your application id");
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Parse-REST-API-Key", "your REST API key");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
var result = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
if (result.objectId) {
      alert("saved an object with id: " + result.objectId);
    }
  }
}

var data = JSON.stringify({ message: "Hello world!" });
xhr.send(data);
```

I would expect that you can include the headers in your GET requests as well.